# jquery ui accordion not autoheighting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to get this to autoheight as I've got some accordion panels with more content that others but it's leaving a lot off white space, can anyone help? I've tried using the fillspace option, but it leaves a scrollbar on each panel, I've tried the clearstyle option but it jumps up.

```
$(function () {
        var cookieName = 'stickyAccordion';
        $('#accordion').accordion({
            autoHeight: (true),
            collapsible: (true),
            active: ($.cookies.get(cookieName) || 0),
            change: function (e, ui) {

                $.cookies.set(cookieName, $(this).find('h3').index(ui.newHeader[0]));
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Just to be clear, do you need the heights to be the height of the content or set to a certain value regardless of content? Setting autoHeight: false allows to accordion panels to keep their native height.

Comment: Can you post an example (from jsfiddle maybe?).

Comment: +1 for the work autoheighting

Answer (score 0):

`heightStyle: "content"` should solve your problem but I found that setting `autoHeight: false` solved it for me. I've been tearing my remaining hair out for an hour over this (though I realise you've probably solved this by now).

Answer (score -1):

I found that:

```
autoHeight: false
```

Solved my problem. Give it a shot.